# Program unresponsive until function is done

Tags: c++, forms

Visual Studio, C++, Form application

(I'm new to Visual C++)

I have an application which has a button who's function is very complex and it takes about a minute to finish.

Also: As long as the function runs the program becomes unresponsive. The window is updated when this->Refresh(); is called, but when I click somewhere into the window, then it's not even updated anymore. The function continues to run until it is done with its job and then everything is back to normal.

I want to be able to click a "Stop" button.

How do I do that?

Comment: You should consider putting that "long process" into a background thread.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is multithreading... if your application has a single thread and it is busy performing the calculation, then it will not be able to do anything else, like update the UI or handle events ("Stop" button)

Answer (score 2):

It's because the main thread of a windows program runs the message pump (which does things like painting the screen) and as long as your function runs you're blocking that from happening. What you need to do is launch a thread that does your long running task, and when the task completes you can post back to the main thread to update the UI. I haven't done windows programming in years but this was a very common pattern from what I recall.