# C++ System Command Line Call - Hanging GUI

Tags: c++, multithreading, system

This post/question pretty much mimics the symptoms of my issue:
**([Program unresponsive until function is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179858/program-unresponsive-until-function-is-done)).** The symptoms remain in this particular application, even after following that post's advice, so here are the details.

It is a MS Visual C++ CLR application.  It has a GUI that allows the user change some values and then, at the user's click of a button, 1.) first makes a system command line call to a program that partially programs lighting ballasts (this takes about 25 seconds to complete and a command line program is the only option). 2.) second, programs 16 "scene" and "dimming curve" values with the items set by the user in the GUI to the lighting ballasts using C++ code libraries provided by another vendor. The scene and dimming curve programming take a combined total of about 5 seconds to complete.

As per the linked item, when the command line application runs, the GUI for this application hangs. Status updates from the "scene" and "dimming curve" steps do not get displayed in the GUI. As per the advice of what I have read, the command line call is made through a thread call.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
    void main() {
        DWORD ThreadID;
        HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, wfThread, &args, 0, &ThreadID);
        DWORD lpExitCode;
        string strMsg = "";
        do {
            Sleep(1000);
            GetExitCodeThread(hThread, &lpExitCode);
        } while (STILL_ACTIVE == lpExitCode);
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }

    DWORD WINAPI wfThread(LPVOID lpParam) {
        std::stringstream ssCmd;
        ssCmd << "C:\\PROGRA~2\\PHILIP~1\\MULTIO~1.exe /f \"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Data\\driver 929000702302 490ma 60w soco 02001 code.xml\" /w \"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Data\\WorkflowConfig.txt\"  /v info /c halt";
        system(ssCmd.str().c_str());
        return 0;
    }
```

The goal is to get the GUI from hanging during the thread call to this command prompt program, so that when the remaining scene and dimming curve programming occurs, the client can see the status updates as it happens, and not just see the final "PASSED" or "FAILED" message that occurs at the end.

Not sure if it's pertinent or not, but the program does function as expected while the GUI is hung. The lighting ballast gets programmed as expected and the log files get written as expected. There has just been no success in getting the GUI to stop hanging during the command line call and for a few seconds after.

UPDATE:

I have updated the code so the thread is called.  I am still unable to have the main thread (UI) wait / accept any user input without looping, which is still running up the CPU - and on top of that, it **still hangs**, even though MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx is supposed to prevent that, and I'm updating the UI while it's waiting for the thread to complete.

```
        workFlowArgs args = { msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(txtWorkflowProgram->Text), msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(txtXmlFolder->Text), msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(cboXmlSelect->Text), "WorkflowConfig.txt" };
        DWORD ThreadID;
        HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, wfThread, &args, 0, &ThreadID);
        HANDLE hThreads[] = { hThread };
        DWORD lpExitCode;
        string strMsg = "";

        do {
            DWORD res = MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(_countof(hThreads), hThreads, 0, QS_ALLEVENTS, 0);
            if (strMsg == "..........")
                strMsg = "";
            else
                strMsg = strMsg + ".";
            txtStatus->Text = msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(strMsg);
            txtStatus->Refresh();

            switch (res)
            {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0:
                OutputDebugStringW(L"Completed!!");
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + _countof(hThreads):
                OutputDebugStringW(L"Still Going\n");
                txtStatus->Text = msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(strMsg);
                txtStatus->Refresh();
            case WAIT_IO_COMPLETION:
                break;
            }
            GetExitCodeThread(hThread, &lpExitCode);
        }  while (STILL_ACTIVE == lpExitCode);
```

It does seem to take longer for the UI to hang than before (and occassionally it actually does not hang), but I am still actively searching for any ideas on both preventing UI from hanging AND keeping the CPU usage from spiking while it's waiting.  What am I missing?

Comment: Your do/while loop would hang the UI just as effectively as running the command in the main thread.

Comment: @RetiredNinja:  Thank you. I have pondered this. The GUI does hang with extended sleep periods. I have tried putting updates to the GUI in that do/while loop to help avoid that, but still end up with it hanging.  Per requirements (and probably technical limitations of the device I'm programming), I cannot have the command line application running in parallel to the scene & dimming curve programming.  Any suggestions on how to keep the main thread waiting (or at least simulate that it's waiting) until the command line program thread is done?

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Update: The loop was updated with `WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);` and the hanging still occurs.

Comment: Anything you do in your main thread that blocks, whether it is the system command, a sleep in a loop, or a wait forever will freeze your UI.  You need to think of a more event driven or callback type solution.  You can run your long running command in another thread and then notify the main thread when it is finished.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: The long command runs a thread now. I am challenged with how to make the main thread wait for that notification without doing anything that would be blocking/causing a hang, or taxing the CPU (looping without a Sleep command did). Without dev. PC available to me for the next 2 days, I can't see my previous attempts or try anything new.  But I will search for non-blocking thread examples to see what I can find. Can you point me to (or do you have) any examples or algorithms for the main thread while it waits for spawned thread to complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a few weeks frustrating experimentatioin with various threading and message pump solution attempts.  In my research I had read that if the thread was crreating windows, I should use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects or MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx. Well, my system() call IS opening a new window (albeit a Command window), so I kept poking with that. I finally went back to basics (which isn't basic to me, since I have never done threading before) and used GetMessage and created the typical message pump while waiting for the thread to finish.

```
HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, wfThread, &args, 0, &ThreadID);
MSG msg = { 0 };
GetExitCodeThread(hThread, &lpExitCode);
BOOL bRet;
while (((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0) && (STILL_ACTIVE == lpExitCode)) {
    if (bRet == -1)
        // Handle Error
        MessageBox::Show("GetMessage Error");
    else {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    GetExitCodeThread(hThread, &lpExitCode);
}
```